# Polymer google-map component controls seems messed up

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

Having a bit of trouble with google-map controls then I noticed, same issue exist here as well. https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-map

After doing some further analysis it seems loading google map inside polymer component (polymer 2.x & 3.x) having this problem. Maybe some styles are not passed down correctly?

[image: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-map]

This is how mine google map looks like inside a polymer 3 component. Something seems wrong with zoom controls and full screen control. Note: I am not using [google-map](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map) component here. I have a `<div>` inside my component and attaching the map to it like this `this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.$.mapDiv, mapOptions)`

[image]

Appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: This is not github if you have a Problem with this Component raise an issue on Github.

Comment: Posted it here hoping someone might have a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You are using Polymer 3. And the  component is done in Polymer 2...
Maybe, only maybe, they are not compatible and have some issues.

Comment: Only Polymer 1.x seems fine. 2.0 and 3.0 both seems to have this problem

Comment: I was using this component on my own project and with Polymer 2.x was working fine.

Comment: It was OK few days ago, that I can confirm

Answer (score 0):

[image: Google Map Older version]

Did you try the older versions? The preview for v1.2.0 looks okay to me.

Comment: Older versions 1.x.x are fine but we're using polymer 3.0